# use a different T4 template while generating EDMX file - VS2012

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, t4

In VS2012, while using Entity Framework 5.0
when you add an .EDMX file (ADO.NET Data Model) file to your project, VS uses 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da740968-02f9-42a9-9ee4-1a9a06d896a2
to generate the context and the entity classes as well.

But, I would like it to generate the code using the following template instead which generates the context, entity classes and fluent API mapping classes as well.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d663b99-ed3b-481d-b7bc-b947d2457e3c

Is there a way to associate this second template with the edmx file so that it automatically uses this template and not the one that comes in VS by default.

Currently, I have to manually delete the code generated by first template and then re-generate it again using the newly added template.  I hope there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently, I have to manually delete the code generated by first
>   template and then re-generate it again using the newly added template.
>   I hope there is a cleaner way.

You just need to delete templates added by default (.tt files) and add templates you want to use.

Comment: Yes, I understand that Ladislav but there must be a way to replace the current T4 being used by VS2012 with the new one.  I need this so every team member in my team is not having to remember to delete existing tt and add new ones... no big deal, I guess!

Comment: How often do you start a new project? You need to do this only once per every project. It is same like adding library to a new project. Not a big deal. If you want to have different default code generation template you must probably write you own item template for Visual Studio.